# Swagger Host Port Missing in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, springfox

spring app + swagger (works on 8080) are working successfully in my local, but when i deploy app on kubernetes, the port information is missing and it calls host without port. so request fails.

in local, these informations are shown in UI like below

```
[ Base URL: localhost:8080/customerservice/api ]
http://localhost:8080/customerservice/api/v2/api-docs
```

in kubernetes deployed,

```
[ Base URL: kubernetes-ip/customerservice/api ]
http://kubernetes-ip:32004/customerservice/api/v2/api-docs
```

but base url must be kubernetes-ip:**32004**/customerservice/api

i have created kubernetes service (nodeport) to access deployment and 32004 is service port.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: customer-service
  namespace: altyapi
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32004
  selector:
    app: customer
  type: NodePort
```

where am i missing here? thanks for helps and suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately..